# Plotting charts in python cmd.Cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to plot some data in CLI. I am looking to plot multiple charts in separate window and it should not block CLI so that I can still give commands in  CLI.

```
class CLI(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def do_plot(self):
        # plot here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CLI().cmdloop()
```

method 1: using matplotlib

I came to know that matplotlib is not thread safe.

method 2: pyqtgraph

I have asked a detail question here : https://forum.qt.io/topic/122033/running-multiple-plots-with-pyside2, still no solution.

Only solution I can think of now is that to write separate program and connect it with CLI using socket and share data. Is there any easy and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Could you specify whether you want the graph to be plotted inside the CLI itself or want an external window to pop open?

Comment: external window.

Comment: @ooo you could have pointed it as feedback to my answer since your post has several interpretations

Comment: @eyllanesc I was waiting if someone else come up with different approach, your currently approach is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt widgets are not thread-safe so in general no widget can (or should) be created and modified in another thread (this involves the Qt backend of matplotlib and pyqtgraph).

Considering the above, a possible alternative is that in the main thread the Qt eventloop lives and in a secondary thread the cmd.Cmd eventloop, and then send the information through signals that are thread-safe.

```py
import cmd
import signal
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class QtSignaller(QtCore.QObject):
    commandChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, object)


class QtShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self, qobject):
        super().__init__()
        self._qobject = qobject

    @property
    def qobject(self):
        return self._qobject

    def do_plot(self, arg):
        self.qobject.commandChanged.emit("plot", parse(arg))


class QtManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._window = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, object)
    def run_command(self, command, parameters):
        x, y = parameters, np.sin(parameters)
        if self._window is None:
            self._window = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
            self._ax = self._window.figure.add_subplot(111)
            self._ax.plot(x, y)
        else:
            self._ax.clear()
            self._ax.plot(x, y)
            self._ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self._window.show()


def run_command(signaller):
    shell = QtShell(signaller)
    shell.cmdloop()


def parse(arg):
    return tuple(map(float, arg.split()))


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    signaller = QtSignaller()
    manager = QtManager()
    signaller.commandChanged.connect(manager.run_command)
    threading.Thread(target=run_command, args=(signaller,), daemon=True).start()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** Although my example uses matplotlib the same logic should be used for pyqtgraph

Comment: Tested the code and it worked like a charm - though I'm unclear if OP actually wants an external window to open (like you suggested): `am trying to plot some data in CLI`. On the other hand he stated: `to plot multiple charts in separate window`. Considering the second statement your solution seems flawless! :)